# Custom class for UITabBarItem in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, uitabbaritem, ios9.3

I have a tabbar with 5 tabs(0,1,2,3,4) at the bottom of the screen and they have different icons. What I am trying to achieve is for the 2nd tab I want a UIView on it and an image inside this UIView.

For this, I tried creating custom UITabBarItem class but I don't see any way I can add UIView in this custom class. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Hope you understand the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you plz post your code? if i understand your qus correctly do you wanna to remove & add 2nd tab bar item based on your data?

Comment: I want to able to add UIView in tabbaritem and an Image inside this view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show one tab in specific condition then you should set `viewcontrollers of tabbabcontroller` something like,

```
  NSMutableArray *tabBarVcArr =  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

[tabBarVcArr removeObjectAtIndex:1];  // this will remove second tab 

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarVcArr;
```

if you want to add tab again then you can instantiate your tabbarcontroller from your storyboard !

That's it!! no need to subclass `UITabBarButtonItem` etc!

Comment: I have edited the question and it makes more sense now about what I am trying to achieve.